# How should I interpret a (badly translated?) params argument from an old COM library?

Tags: c#, api, com

I'm working with an old COM library that I'm accessing through an API. Can't seem to figure out how to use a method with the following signature:

```
aCOMlibrary.AddSearchType(aCOMlibrary.enum.whatever, ref object[])
```

The documentation implies that this can be used in one of two ways:

```
'Method 1
object.AddSearchType ENUM_VALUE


'Method 2
object.AddSearchType ENUM_VALUE_1, ENUM_VALUE_2, ... ENUM_VALUE_n
```

I'm trying to do method 1 in C#:

```
screen.AddSearchType(enum.value);
```

But visual studio complains that I'm providing invalid arguments. So, in an attempt to trick VS, I thought this might work:

```
screen.AddSearchType(enum.value, null);
```

This app compiles and runs, but this line throws an exception about a for-loop not being initialised.

Frustrated, I've decided to try "method 2" from the documentation:

```
screen.AddSearchType(enum.ENUM_VALUE_1, enum.ENUM_VALUE_2);
```

But that throws the following during build:

> > Argument 2: cannot convert from 'aCOMlibrary.enum' to 'ref object[]'

What am I missing? How can I coax this knackered old COM library to do my bidding?

Comment: Um, by passing it a `ref object[]`?

Comment: `screen.AddSearchType(enum.ENUM_VALUE_1, ref new object[1]{enum.ENUM_VALUE_2});` or even `screen.AddSearchType(enum.ENUM_VALUE_1, ref new object[0]);`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turned out I needed to pass it

```
new object[1] {enum.ENUM_VALUE_2}
```

Matt's comment got me most of the way, but his suggestions resulted in:

> > A ref or out argument must be an assignable variable

So I dropped the `ref` and it compiled. Thanks for your help!